# Quotes don't work with polyglossia?

Tags: polyglossia

I have an older file using `` and '' which would then be formatted as proper quotes. I was now wanting to use polyglossia for that file and find that while these quotes still work in the footnotes, they don't do so anymore in the running text:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{sanskrit}
\setotherlanguage{german}
\newfontfamily\sanskritfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\newfontfamily\englishfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\begin{document}
``Test''\footnote{``Test''}
\end{document}
```

[image: running text] [image: footnote]

Was I just using some ancient crutch one should not be using anymore nowadays?

Comment: Please tell us which TeX distribution and which version of either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX you use.

Comment: @Mico XeTeX 3.14159265-2.6-0.99996 (TeX Live 2016)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you define an `\englishfont` you need to activate the ligatures for it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{sanskrit}
\setotherlanguage{german}
\newfontfamily\sanskritfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\newfontfamily\englishfont{Latin Modern Roman}[Ligatures=TeX]
\begin{document}
``Test''\footnote{``Test''}
\end{document}
```

[image]