# Polyglossia with Russian language set does not render -- and --- and nice quotes

Tags: punctuation, polyglossia, russian

Using `polyglossia` package with `\setdefaultlanguage{russian}` stops producing en-dashes and em-dashes from `--` and `---`, respectively. Also, no more nice 'upper 99' quotemarks (or any other nice quotemarks) from U+0022.

With `\setdefaultlanguage{english}` or with default language I get those. With `russian` I don't. The closest I've come was with `babelshorthands=true` option, but there are three issues:

1. the rendering result doesn't look nice (line thickness visibly varies, at least with this font),
2. spacing with `"--` (or `"--~` for that matter) and linebreak after `"---`,
3. and of course having to use sequences which are mightily inconvenient if writing text in Russian.

I could of course directly input U+2014 and U+2015 and nice quotemarks, but why the package exhibits such strange behaviour at all? No language set (English?) works nice.

I need hyphenation, or I'd just ditch `polyglossia`, and `babel` conflicts with something I need.

The MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Liberation Serif}[Ligatures=TeX]
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfont{Liberation Serif}[Script=Cyrillic]
\usepackage{polyglossia}

% these work (german - in its own specific manner):
%\setdefaultlanguage{english}
%\setdefaultlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{german}

% these don't (strange results with babelshorthands on):
\setdefaultlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{russian}
%\setdefaultlanguage[babelshorthands=false]{russian}
%\setdefaultlanguage{russian}

% polyglossia version: 2023/02/11 v1.60
\begin{document}

..........

-- ~ "en-dash"

--- ~ "em-dash"

"-- ~ "babelshorthands en-dash"

"--- ~ "babelshorthands em-dash"

\end{document}
```

UPDATE: The suggested reference '[Quotes don't work with polyglossia](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339300/quotes-dont-work-with-polyglossia)?', while it offers a solution actually,  doesn't qualify as a 'precise' duplicate, I think,  because the OP's question there is formulated in such way so that's easy to miss the issue's relation to my question.

Comment: You should set `Ligatures=TeX` for the Cyrillic font as well.

Comment: @Marijn Thank you! So that was all there was to it? That instruction always looked sort of not like a new font, but like a mapping to an existing one. Make an answer from your note, I'll raise it.
However, the second part still remains -- dashes as generated by those special " sequences look strangely.

Comment: @yury10578 Never ask more than one question in one question. Always focus to one problem per question.

Comment: @cabohah Thank you! It could answer the question, only it looks like it's sort of hard to stumble upon. I didn't see it in search engines or in site's suggestions.

Comment: @cabohah Looked like one-source issue to me. To make a separate issue from it would require researching, though. I haven't used those babel " sequences before, saw them in search engines.

Comment: The thickness part is probably caused by the drawing of the Cyrillic dashes, which have a special length of 0.8em, as two overlapping Latin dashes (see https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues/445#issuecomment-698905078), this can lead to incorrect rendering in some pdf viewers at some zoom levels.

Comment: Yeah, the sort of famous issue #445 which pops up early in search engines. 
But wait, how come the default setting in polyglossia work okay? Does it request Ligatures=TeX automatically then?

Comment: @cabohah Having looked at you suggestion again, I think it doesn't quite qualify. 
The OP there talks about some old tricks with quotes ``'', so the reference's relation to my problem isn't visible too clearly.

Comment: Have you tested the suggested solutions from the answers? The reference relation is the usage and enabling of TeX ligatures, when using `\newfontfamily` (and indirect also usage of correct starting and ending quotes. BTW: I would suggest to use package `csquotes` for quotes like shown, e.g., at [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/564167/277964) or [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/473127/277964).)

Comment: @cabohah Of course I did, right away. But I'm not a pro in Latex, not by a long shot. It just wasn't obvious to me how the talk about ``quotes'' relates to my simple "quotes" - and dashes, too.

(And I remember seeing lots of unwieldy TeX tricks in olden times.)

Comment: Re “babel conflicts with something I need”, feel free to ask for help. Maybe your conflict can be solved or there is a workaround.

Comment: @Javier Bezos Thank you! It's just I've had this issue 2 years ago, switched to polyglossia then, and since then have forgotten about the issue completely. I deal only occasionaly with Latex-based big projects, mostly it's small stuff. I've just looked into my 2 yrs old notes, and there's something about 'babel conflicts with Greek in maths' (??) It must be with {mathspec} and \setmathsfont(Digits,Latin,Greek){Liberation Serif} which I have there? Go figure. Hope it helps a bit.
Anyway, that'

Comment: @yury10578 2 years ago babel was version 3.73.  Currently we use version 24.3. babel is one of the packages with excellent support and therefore steady improvement. I wouldn't be surprised if a problem from 2 years ago no longer existed. If it does, a question about it and possibly a report would certainly be useful.

Comment: @cabohah Afraid the full info is lost, so we won't know what had been going wrong 2 years ago.

As for today, I just gave babel a quick try, and I'm honestly impressed. Maybe something will crop up yet, but I can't make it misbehave as of now, also with the mathspec sequence from my notes. I'm definitely 'taking it for a spin'.

Documentation is comprehensive and pleasant-looking. Version tags are quite a nice touch.

Comment: @cabohah Well, no luck with babel, after all. I can't use both a language with babelshorthands defined AND plain doublequotes U+0022. The following space gets 'eaten', and I see in other questions discussions that's an unavoidable effect. I use orgmode for my writing, and going to things like ``'' and \textquotedbl (are you kidding me) definitely seems like a cure worse than illness. Thought I'd let you know.

Comment: You've not understand how to make quotes correctly and how shortcuts like `"` work. To say it once again clearly: [`"` for quotes is wrong!](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/405718/277964) not only TeXnical but also typographical. There is nothing else I can or should say.

Answer (score 1):

With `\newfontfamily` you need to enable TeX-Ligatures, if they should be uses, e.g., for `--` or `---` or also for quotes. Use

```
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfont{Liberation Serif}[Script=Cyrillic,Ligatures=TeX]
```

similar to your already used:

```
\setmainfont{Liberation Serif}[Ligatures=TeX]
```

(BTW: Usually `Ligatures=TeX` is already set for the main font and therefore not needed.) See also question “[Quotes don't work with polyglossia?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339300/quotes-dont-work-with-polyglossia)”

Additionally I would suggest to use package `csquotes` for the quotation as shown [in this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/473127/277964). Depending on the quotation style you want, you can additionally use option `style`, e.g.

```latex
\usepackage[style=american]{csquotes}
```

However it seems, that the babel shorthands `"--~` and `"---` do not work correctly with `polyglossia`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Liberation Serif}
%\usepackage[english,main=russian]{babel}
\setmainfont{Liberation Serif}[Ligatures=TeX]
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfont{Liberation Serif}[Script=Cyrillic]
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{russian}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\usepackage[style=american]{csquotes}

\defineshorthand{"`}{\openautoquote}
\defineshorthand{"'}{\closeautoquote}

\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{english}\useshorthands{"}

-- ``en-dash''

--- ``em-dash''

"--~ ``babelshorthands em-dash no space''

"--- ``babelshorthands em-dash small space''

\selectlanguage{russian}

-- "`тире"'

--- "`рывок"'

"--~ "`вавилонские сокращения, тире, нет места"'

"--- "`вавилонская стенография em-dash маленькое пространство"'

\end{document}
```

[image]

You would need to redefine these shorthands, too, but
IMHO it is easier to use `babel` instead of `polyglossia` if you want to use `babel` shorthands:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Liberation Serif}% explicit option [Ligatures=TeX] not needed
\usepackage[english,main=russian]{babel}
\usepackage[style=american]{csquotes}

\defineshorthand{"`}{\openautoquote}
\defineshorthand{"'}{\closeautoquote}

\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{english}

-- ``en-dash''

--- ``em-dash''

"--~ ``babelshorthands em-dash no space''

"--- ``babelshorthands em-dash small space''

\selectlanguage{russian}
% Note: All translations by translate.google.com

-- "`тире"'

--- "`рывок"'

"--~ "`вавилонские сокращения, тире, нет места"'

"--- "`вавилонская стенография em-dash маленькое пространство"'

\end{document}
```

[image]

Because `babel` shorthands are language depending, `"--~` and `"---` are ignored in the English part.

Comment: In fact, one should not activate [babelshorthands=true] with polyglossia with Russian (or with other languages, too?) if not actually using babel shorthands in the text.
What happens is space after closing quote mark gets 'eaten'.